# What script executes after clicking the button (Web app)?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests

I'm automating the manual testing of some Web Application.

This app uses a lot number of JavaScript. And I want to know, what scripts executes when I manually clicking some button.
Here is the example of button's code:

```
<button type="button" class="x-btn-text " id="ext-gen525" title="Add Options">Add</button>
```

This button adds row into table on page using AJAX.
As you can see, declaration of this button not contain block "onclick" or something like this.
How can I know what script executes on clicking this button?

Comment: Removed 'java' tag; java is not javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use Firefox javascript profiler (comes with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/))
you simply go to the page, wait for it to load completely, activate the profiler, click the button, deactivate the profiler and what you will see is a list of functions that were activated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to search the javascript file to see where they are adding the event handler. Most of the time people will use

```
document.getElementById("ext-gen525")
```

to reference the element they want to add it to. Try searching the .js file for the id "ext-gen525" and you should see the function they are adding to the onclick event.

Comment: Thank you, I'm doing this now, but app has big number of different js-files (((
Maybe exists easier way to do this?